# My Bluetooth has disappeared from my computer. (Lenovo Laptop - Ubuntu Studio) How can I get it back?

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo, ubuntu-studio

I can't find `em bluetooth` on my Lenovo -ubuntu studio laptop. It is an application that I often use to transfer files from my mobile. But lately the system is updating me automatically, and it is changing the appearance of the desktop and many settings without asking.

I don't understand how an application as basic as bluetooth could have completely disappeared from my computer and I can't find it either through the search engine, or through the system, or in the list of applications.

Could you advise me or help me solve this problem.

Comment: This is an English only site I'm afraid, please edit your question and give in English only...

Comment: It is unclear if you visited the manual, from Ubuntu, on Bluetooth before posting (https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth.html , at bottom of that page, you can change the Language, when needed)